# Selecting a tag in 1 line of code with nth-of-type, can't use nth-child

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a CSS selection to scrape temperature data from a web page I'm unable to edit. The full code is this one liner below:

```
<b>handler.setget(<tt>%sen-1</tt>)</b><br><tt>23.150</tt>
```

I made the page below to debug, in this case, I'm trying to make the temperature value red. nth-child(3) works but it's not supported by my scraper, Is there a way to do this differently? Oddly `body>tt:nth-of-type(1)` works with my debugger but it doesn't work in my scraper.

Any ideas?

```css
tt:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<b>handler.setget(<tt>%sen-1</tt>)</b>
<br>
<tt>21.560</tt>
```

Comment: you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors `br + tt{background: red;}`

Comment: don't add only CSS, add the relevant tag of your scrapper, this is clearly not a CSS issue since you said the selector is working fine